# CakePHP Distinct query over multiple tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, left-join, distinct

I need to do a Distinct search in the following query:

```
$listings = $this->Listing->query("SELECT DISTINCT(Listing.listnumber),Listing.*, ClientEvent.*, Client.*, UserLog.*, Agent.* FROM listings Listing
                        LEFT JOIN client_events ClientEvent ON ClientEvent.listnumber = Listing.listnumber
                        LEFT JOIN clients Client ON Client.clnt_id = ClientEvent.clnt_id
                        LEFT JOIN user_logs UserLog ON UserLog.ul_item_id = Listing.listnumber
                        LEFT JOIN agents Agent ON Agent.agnt_id = Listing.agnt_id
                        WHERE Listing.off_id = '{$off_id}' AND (UserLog.ul_type = 'listing.new_listing' OR Listing.listnumber LIKE '3330%')");
```

However, this gives me the correct result, but duplicates. I need DISTINCT results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    $listings = $this->Listing->query("SELECT Listing.listnumber FROM listings Listing
                            LEFT JOIN client_events ClientEvent ON ClientEvent.listnumber = Listing.listnumber
                            LEFT JOIN clients Client ON Client.clnt_id = ClientEvent.clnt_id
                            LEFT JOIN user_logs UserLog ON UserLog.ul_item_id = Listing.listnumber
                            LEFT JOIN agents Agent ON Agent.agnt_id = Listing.agnt_id
                            WHERE Listing.off_id = '{$off_id}' AND (UserLog.ul_type = 'listing.new_listing' OR Listing.listnumber LIKE '3330%') group by Listing.listnumber");
----------------------
Put your extar column not a tablename.*...

    $listings = $this->Listing->query("SELECT Listing.listnumber, colname1,.. FROM listings Listing
                            LEFT JOIN client_events ClientEvent ON ClientEvent.listnumber = Listing.listnumber
                            LEFT JOIN clients Client ON Client.clnt_id = ClientEvent.clnt_id
                            LEFT JOIN user_logs UserLog ON UserLog.ul_item_id = Listing.listnumber
                            LEFT JOIN agents Agent ON Agent.agnt_id = Listing.agnt_id
                            WHERE Listing.off_id = '{$off_id}' AND (UserLog.ul_type = 'listing.new_listing' OR Listing.listnumber LIKE '3330%') group by Listing.listnumber");
```

Comment: this is for a stock report that exports to Excel. Your answer makes sense but doesn't word as it gives an empty result when called in the view

Comment: you are remove this condition from query : WHERE Listing.off_id = '{$off_id}' AND (UserLog.ul_type = 'listing.new_listing' OR Listing.listnumber LIKE '3330%')

Comment: so, we are find out data is there after filter

Comment: This can and should be done by using the model associations and NOT a plain query like this.